# What is the purpose of the Zero member when defining F# computation expressions?

Tags: f#, computation-expression

I am trying to learn F# computation expressions.  In general, what is the purpose of the Zero member?

What is its definition for sequences?

What is its definition for async workflows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Zero` member is used, for example, when you omit the `else` branch in an `if` expression:

```
comp { if b then return 1
       return 2 }
```

... would be translated to something like this:

```
comp.Combine
  ( if b then comp.Return(1) else comp.Zero(),
    comp.Return(2) )
```

How is it defined for standard computation types?

- For asynchronous workflows, it is defined as asynchronous workflow that immediately returns a unit value - essentially equivalent to writing: `async { return () }`.
- For sequences (where you use `yield` instead of `return`) the `Zero` member returns a sequence that does not return anything, corresponding to the standard `Seq.empty` value.

If you want to read about some more theoretical background, then you can [check out this paper](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~tp322/drafts/notations.pdf). In a more theoretical terms, it says that `Zero` is either going to be `return ()` (when the computation is a monad) or it is going to be the unit of a monoid (when the computation is monoidal) which is something that Haskellers call `mzero`.